# Javascript Auto Update

Tags: javascript, refresh

In my stream page, I have one current song script, but it doesn't update... The user needs to refresh the page.

the script is:

```
<script name="whasong" id="whasongid" src="http://xxxx.xxxx.net/js/song/u4:2134" type="text/javascript">
You appear to have javascript turned off.
</script>
```

src="http://xxxx.xxxx.net/js/song/u4:2134" code:

```
document.write('SONG NAME');
```

Is it possible to autoupdate just this script without refreshing the whole page ?

Comment: You need something that triggers the update of the current song. An event that fires, whenever the user starts listening to the next song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be in need of Ajax functionality. Do you mean that, at the end of a song playing, you want to modify the page content to reflect the song change? If it is so, you might gain a lot by looking into a JavaScript framework like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.org) or [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and bind some behavior to the state change in question. So you will want the song change (for example) to trigger a certain function you will have prepared, which will use jQuery to query the server via Ajax to update the page, and change the DOM accordingly.

**EDIT**: If instead of waiting for an explicit state change in your web page, you wanted to update it periodically, you might be looking for such a strategy :

```js
function updatePage(/* arguments */) {
  // Call the server to get some data ...
  // Update the page accordingly ...
  if (/* continue updating the page? */) setTimeout(60000 /* 60 seconds */, updatePage);
}
```

If you were using [jQuery for your Ajax needs](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for instance, that function could look like so :

```js
function updatePage(/* arguments */) {
  jQuery.get("/your/url", {foo: "bar"}, function(data) {
    // Update the page accordingly ...
    if (/* continue updating the page? */) setTimeout(60000 /* 60 seconds */, updatePage);
  });
}
```

If you want some more specific help, don't hesitate to be more precise as to what your issue is.

Comment: I just edited the answer to give some examples for updating on a periodical manner.